# python - Why main thread print ended line before all threads join

Tags: python

I call to join , so i dont understand why the main thread print 'End' before all threaded were finished.
The output is :

```
End
Thread
Thread
```

Additional related question:
Just to make sure if is set daemon flag to true, is it mean that there is no meaning to call to join (because main can be finished when there are still daemon threads)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import threading
from time import sleep

num_worker_threads = 2                  
threads = []   

def worker():
    sleep(1)
    print 'Thread'

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
     threads.append(t)
     t.start()
     t.join

print 'End'
```

Comment: It should be t.join() i think..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you actually don't call join. Replace:

```
t.join
```

with:

```
t.join()
```

The point is that `t.join` expression returns `bound method` object, and adding parentheses makes expression to be a method call.

Joining threads matters only for user threads, daemon threads will not block main thread to finish.

Comment: WOW. Stupid stupid me!!!!! what about the second question? i will mark this as an answer.

Comment: You should elaborate on _why_ this is, because it's an interesting teaching point! In general, python functions require a set of parentheses after them. Otherwise, you're actually referencing the method itself. Is the OP aware of that?

Comment: @rsegal so why there is no error on the join without the parentheses

Comment: @user1495181, I've updated my answer to show why parentheses are so important there.

Comment: @user1495181 to elaborate on his point, Python (like most object-oriented languages) allows you to pass a _reference to a method_ instead of calling it. `t.join` is actually the name of a method, packaged as a `bound method` object, whereas `t.join()` actually calls the method. Referring to methods like that is often used for [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) in code.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the brackets after `t.join`. It should be `t.join()`.